# Uploading JSON to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Update: I will answer this myself immediately (this code works):

My customized upload code based off: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery#loaddatapostrequest

```
import sys
import json

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenRefreshError
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.tools import run
from apiclient.errors import HttpError

import httplib2

FLOW = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
    client_id='xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    client_secret='shhhhhhhhhhhh',
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery',
    user_agent='my-program-name/1.0')

def loadTable(http, service):
  projectId = 'drc-compute'
  datasetId = 'standing'
  import time
  tableId = 'test_' + str(int(time.time()))

  url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/" + projectId + "/jobs"
  schema = open('test_schema.json', 'r')

  # Create the body of the request, separated by a boundary of xxx
  newresource = ('--xxx\n' +
            'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\n' + '\n' +
            '{\n' +
            '   "configuration": {\n' +
            '     "load": {\n' +
            '     "sourceFormat": "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON",\n' +
            '      "schema": {\n'
            '         "fields": ' + schema.read() + '\n' +
            '      },\n' +
            '      "destinationTable": {\n' +
            '        "projectId": "' + projectId + '",\n' +
            '        "datasetId": "' + datasetId + '",\n' +
            '        "tableId": "' + tableId + '"\n' +
            '      }\n' +
            '    }\n' +
            '  }\n' +
            '}\n' +
            '--xxx\n' +
            'Content-Type: application/octet-stream\n' +
            '\n')

  # Append data from the specified file to the request body
  f = open('test.json', 'r')
  newresource += f.read().replace('\n', '\r\n')

  # Signify the end of the body
  newresource += ('--xxx--\n')

  print newresource

  headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/related; boundary=xxx'}
  resp, content = http.request(url, method="POST", body=newresource, headers=headers)

  if not resp.status == 200:
    print resp
    print content
  else:
    jsonResponse = json.loads(content)
    jobReference = jsonResponse['jobReference']['jobId']
    import time
    while True:
     jobCollection = service.jobs()
     getJob = jobCollection.get(projectId=projectId, jobId=jobReference).execute()
     currentStatus = getJob['status']['state']

     if 'DONE' == currentStatus:
      print "Done Loading!"
      return

     else:
      print 'Waiting to load...'
      print 'Current status: ' + currentStatus
      print time.ctime()
      time.sleep(10)

def main(argv):
  # If the credentials don't exist or are invalid, run the native client
  # auth flow. The Storage object will ensure that if successful the good
  # credentials will get written back to a file.
  storage = Storage('bigquery2.dat') # Choose a file name to store the credentials.
  credentials = storage.get()
  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run(FLOW, storage)

  # Create an httplib2.Http object to handle our HTTP requests and authorize it
  # with our good credentials.
  http = httplib2.Http()
  http = credentials.authorize(http)

  service = build('bigquery','v2', http=http)

  #datasets = service.datasets().list(projectId='917370487687').execute()

  loadTable(http, service)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(sys.argv)
```

You'll need your own bigquery `client_id` and `client_secret` to replicate in addition to running it once on a machine you can open a browser and log in to google with. Then bigquery2.dat will then store oauth2 refresh tokens and such. The simple test data I'm playing with is just:

**test.json**

```
{"asdf": "dd"}
{"asdf": "ax"}
```

**test_schema.json**

```
[
  {
    "type": "STRING",
    "name": "asdf",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  }
]
```

Comment: Basically just remember to set `sourceFormat` within the load properties to `NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To not leave this question open, as you already answered it in the question section - thanks to @noonien comment:

> "remember to set sourceFormat within the load properties to
>   NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON"